# Error: Bootstrap's JavaScript requires jQuery AngularJS- jQuery is linked

Tags: jquery, angularjs, bootstrapping

I have a small project I just started using angular 1.5 and off the bat I'm getting an error that jQuery needs to be used for bootstrap, which I have included in the scripts before the bootstrap js. Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Sorry this link did not appear!

https://gist.github.com/megdollar/921ec2ae979fbb0c464db14ce608220f

Comment: You really need to show some code.  Have you tried starting out with a simple hello world in Plunker and expanding from there? A lite version of jQuery is built-in to angularjs.  I've never had a need to use the full library with Angular.

Comment: Sorry about that my link was in script tags and did not appear https://gist.github.com/megdollar/921ec2ae979fbb0c464db14ce608220f

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, since there is no code to view, that you are trying to pull in the full version of JQuery?

I just did a quick Hello World plunker with Angularjs and Bootstrap without any problems.  See if your code is similar to what I have below.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <link data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" rel="stylesheet" href="Bootstrap" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.3" data-semver="1.5.3" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.3/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="bootstrap.js@3.3.6" data-semver="3.3.6" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Hello Plunker!</h1>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Oopsies here is the gist link https://gist.github.com/megdollar/921ec2ae979fbb0c464db14ce608220f